# Runtime Exception when implementing listview in fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to implement list view in fragment. But when I launch the app it crashes. Here is the code for HomeFragment.java class

```
package info.nadimemon.slidingmenu;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class HomeFragment extends ListFragment {

public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


    String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_home, R.id.label, adobe_products));


    return rootView;
}
```

}

here is my logcat

```
03-14 20:06:27.554    1099-1099/info.androidhive.slidingmenu W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
03-14 20:06:27.574    1099-1099/info.androidhive.slidingmenu E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
            at android.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:402)
            at android.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:203)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:842)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4474)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1929)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 20:06:27.684    1099-1105/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-14 20:06:27.704    1099-1105/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-14 20:06:28.144    1099-1105/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-14 20:06:28.174    1099-1105/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

How can I solve this problem? I am following these two tutorial.
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/
Thank you

Comment: Can you post your MainActivity.java and layouts?

Comment: in the bottom of this page you will find MainActivity. I did not change this class yet. http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Answer (score 0):

```
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_home, R.id.label, adobe_products));
```

Instead of this.give an id to the listview in your fragment xml then find that listview by id and then set the adapter to that

```
    ListView yourListView=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.yourid);
    yourListView.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.fragment_home, R.id.label, adobe_products));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your xml layout you have  `listView` and because
 you are extending `ListFragment` you should change your `listView` id to :

`android:id="@id/android:list"`